# Pin a Excel 2013 workbook to taskbar with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way of pinning a workbook to the Excel pinned items list, using VBA?

I've researched the internet high and low, but can't seem to find any good examples or even if a method is possible?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: by the file just being open to run the VBA should pin it

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/where-are-pinned-documents-stored-in-office-2013/b10a9335-3f0e-4f24-aeb1-bb86a5183c67

Comment: @bvmcode the workbook will be on the recent list, but not pinned.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams - I'll see if I can make something work with adding registry keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Williams in the comments above, I was able to get a VBA code to add / remove registry keys that would pin and unpin items.

```
If RegKeyExists("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\BEApplication\") = False Then
        ' Code for adding registry key
            Dim myWS As Object, strPath
            strPath = <Folder Path>
            Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

            myWS.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\BEApplication\Path",strPath,"REG_SZ"


    Else
        ' Key exists - do nothing
End If
```